# Ruby: why does an undeclared instance variable return nil

Tags: ruby

Given the following class:

```
class Something
  def initialize
    @test = "test"
  end
end
```

Why does ruby return nil when invoking an undeclared instance variable?

```
thingy = Something.new
thingy.instance_variable_get(:@var)  # nil
thingy.instance_variable_get(:@test) # "test"
```

As opposed to some error message indicating the variable is missing from the instance.  The answer I am hoping for is an explanation as to the reasoning behind ruby's implementation of instance variables in this way.

Comment: What will happen if such an error was indeed reported?  Should all Ruby program terminate abnormally just because one tried to access an uninitialised variable?

Comment: @WandMaker: well, ruby programs do crash when you try to access an uninitialized local variable. The question is, why instance variables behave differently?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: No, they don't: `if false then foo = 42 end; foo #=> nil`

Comment: @JörgWMittag: yeah, right. Now try to access `bar` and see your program crash.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: That's a method call, not because local variables don't evaluate to `nil`. Local variables are created at parse time, when the parser sees an assignment. If there hasn't been an assignment, then it's a method call, not a local variable. The fact that you are getting a `NameError` instead of a `NoMethodError` is just Ruby trying to be helpful (wrongly, in my opinion). The error message says "local variable **or method**".

Comment: @JörgWMittag: yes, you're right. I wasn't fully awake :)

Answer (score 2):

It's just the way instance variables implemented in Ruby. Same for global variables. Also you can see warnings for such things if you pass `-w` parameter to ruby.

```
✗ irb -w
2.3.1 :001 > @a
(irb):1: warning: instance variable @a not initialized
=> nil
```

Comment: That answer makes sense.  I guess I am wondering though if there is a fundamental reason for why it is implemented this way.

Comment: Ruby is a  very programmer friendly language. There are many examples of this for example new operator '&.' . I don't see any other reasons behind this behaviour.

Comment: If it's helpful, @dtburgess, I reason about variables in Ruby as symbols being bound to values. That means that interrogating a symbol with no previous definition has `nil`, the not-a-value value. I don't have a citation that this is the original author's intent, but this mental model has been consistent in all the Ruby reasoning I've done.

Comment: Also, local variables: `if false then foo = 42 end; foo #=> nil`

Answer (score 0):

Because, instead of throwing an error, objects are allowed to have empty values. Such as a user, must have a name and address but email address is optional, a check can be done for nil before continuing.

```
if customer1.name == nil #personalized error code here
if customer1.email == nil customer1.email = "not given"
```

Comment: Use `.nil?` if you must, but 99.9% of the time `unless x` is sufficient. It's only when you're dealing with values that could be literal `false` the distinction is necessary.